# toDataURL generates one of two errors: canvas.toDataURL is not a function OR Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, canvas

The users in my website upload a profile image crop it then send it to the server. After the image is cropped it is put in a canvas then is sent by ajax. To convert the canvas into an image i am using toDataURL. the problem is when I use

convertCanvasToImage(imgData[0]);

I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined

and when i remove the [0]

convertCanvasToImage(imgData);

I get:

Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function

Code is below:

```
imgData = pCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 150, 100);

iEdit.callback(iEdit.processCan.toDataURL("image/" + iEdit.imageType, 
iEdit.imageQuality));

iEdit.close();
remove_profile_image = "False";
var image = $("#file-upload");
var data = imgData;
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
var my_canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 150, 100);
//this is either data = convertCanvasToImage(imgData[0]); or
data = convertCanvasToImage(imgData);
$.ajax({
    url: $(image).attr("data-url"),
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $(image).siblings("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": CSRF_TOKEN,
        "profile_image": data
    },
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN": csrftoken
    },
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data1) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
}
```

and this the convertCanvasToImage function

```
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
return image;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `var data = imgData.data`; I would have preferred an working example

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `ImageData` as param to `convertCanvasToImage`. And [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) doesn't have a `toDataUrl` as it contains the raw pixels.

You need to pass as param the original canvas that holds the image. `pCtx` is not the canvas, but the 2d context and it is not clear from your question how you access the canvas.